# How to compile fortran with HDF5 1.14.1 in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, hdf5

I am struggling to setup my fortran project properly. My project configuration is set to Release x64. When I put 'use hdf5' in my fortran module, I get:
error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [H5ES]

I set up the project properties as follows:

> Fortran/General/Additional Include Directories = C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.14.1\mod\static

> Linker/General/Additional Library Directories = C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.14.1\lib

> Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies = libhdf5.lib libhdf5_fortran.lib

I have tried different combinations of settings but no luck. Where am I going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Where is the HDF5 compiled module file?

Comment: @francescalus I believe that would be hdf5.mod, which is in C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.14.1\mod\static